# Passing a multidimensional list pointer in scheme

Tags: list, multidimensional-array, scheme, declaration, using

I am trying to declare a multidimensional list and use it by reference (under scheme)

```
(let* (
      (big-list (list '(0 0 8 4 255 255) '(0 0 16 6 255 255)))
      (small-list 0) (v1 0) (v2 0) (v3 0)
      ))

(set! small-list (car(big-list)))

(set! v1 (car(small-list)))

(set! v2 (cadr(small-list)))
```

etc..

As you wise and experienced schemers can see it is not working.
I suspect that "big-list" obviously needs some special treatment in declaration and access (Illegal function!), and I am afraid I have scoured the web some but have been unable to find guidance.

Any kind soul please help ?

Comment: Sincere apologies for the typo multimensional in the header of the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of `let` and `let*` is `(let <bindings> <body>)`.
The bindings are only available in the body. Your example becomes:

```
(let* ((big-list (list '(0 0 8 4 255 255) '(0 0 16 6 255 255)))
       (small-list 0)
       (v1 0)
       (v2 0)
       (v3 0))
  (set! small-list (car big-list))
  (set! v1 (car small-list))
  (set! v2 (cadr small-list))

  (display "v1 ") (display v1) (newline)
  (display "v2 ") (display v2) (newline))
```

Here `(set! v1 (car small-list))` is moved into the body of the let.

An alternative is to use `define` :

```
(define big-list (list '(0 0 8 4 255 255) '(0 0 16 6 255 255)))
(define small-list 0)
(define v1 0)
(define v2 0)
(define v3 0)

(set! small-list (car big-list))
(set! v1 (car small-list))
(set! v2 (cadr small-list))

(display "v1 ") (display v1) (newline)
(display "v2 ") (display v2) (newline)
```

Comment: Thank you soegaard. It works like a charm. I decided to go with the (define approach. I also learned something very interesting about the behaviour of (car. By not encapsulating the list name in parens you helped me avoid the illegal function error. A function would use the encapsulated approach to -return- the list pointer to car for "dereferencing" suitable assignment to a variable or use. Superb learning today.